# PySpark MongoDB append all elements of an array from DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pymongo, apache-spark-sql

I have a MongoDB collection that looks something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : { "customerName" : "Bob",  "customerPhone" : "123-456-7890"},
    "purchases": ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
}
```

Basically the _id is a pair of unique key about the customer and the purchases are the array of the items that the customer has bought.

I also have a PySpark DataFrame that I would like to push into this collection where it contains information that I would like to update this particular document.

```
df.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").mode("append") \
                .option("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/customer.purchases").save()
```

The problem is that if I am updating this document where I want to add new purchases for Bob it would only append the non-existing ones in `purchases` instead of appending all.

As a result what I ended up doing right now is that I would just have to call `rdd.collect()` to turn the whole thing into a list and not using the schema to convert it to DataFrame. Then insert everything one by one while checking if the key exists; which makes this part slow and requires a lot of memory when the query for RDD gets large.

For versions:

PySpark: 2.2
MongoDB: 3.0.15
Mongo Spark Connector: 2.2.1

Does anyone if there is anything that I can do to append all element in the array to MongoDB collection using dataframe?
Also, if there is anything that I am missing or other things that I should do please let me know.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the [data models](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/data-modeling/) or schema of your documents. The important part here being the `_id` key field. The field name `_id` is reserved for use as a primary key; its value must be unique in the collection, is *immutable*, and may be of any type other than an array.

In your case, the value of `_id` field is mutable, in fact this is what you're trying to update. As a suggestion, you may want to change this to:

```
{ "_id" : <unique identifier>
  "customerName" : "Bob",  
  "customerPhone" : "123-456-7890",
  "purchases": ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
}
```

You may utilise the default `_id` value of [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) as a unique identifier.

Once you have a unique identifier on `_id` field, let's talk about update operation. Since [MongoDB Spark Connector](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/) v1.1+ (currently version 2.2), if a Dataframe contains an `_id` field during write, the data will be [upsert-ed](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#mongodb30-upsert-id). Which means any existing documents with the same _id value will be updated and new documents without existing _id value in the collection will be inserted.

Bonus rounds:

- You need to find a better schema as well for `purchases` field. Having an array length of undefined length may create issues in the future. i.e. Bob made 1000 purchases in a year.
- Please update your MongoDB server version (version 3.0.x is from 2015), the current stable version is 3.4, with 3.6 being released in the next month.

Comment: thanks for the reply. For my use case I can guarantee that `customerName` and `customerPhone` will always be a unique key pair. It's also difficult to find the `_id` when using the ObjectID because then it would be one more extra step to find it and collecting all the data from the worker nodes to the master node would be expensive. Do you know if there is another way to do it?

Comment: If you follow the example schema above, you will still be able to query record(s) using either `customerName` and `customerPhone` , or both. This also works for your MongoDB Spark upsert. `_id` is reserved as a unique primary key, if you were to store a sub-document in `_id` you have to supply  both fields in that order. I recommend to consider your schema. Please also see [Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/) and [Compound Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#)